# Is my MySQL query OK or can it be improved?

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to select products from MySQL:

Here's what it looks like:

```
SELECT `products`.`id` AS `id`, `products`.`name` AS `name`, `products`.`slug` AS `slug`, `products`.`ord` AS `ord`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(products_photos.name ORDER BY products_photos.ord ASC SEPARATOR ","), ",", 1) AS `photo`, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(products_attributes.price ORDER BY products_attributes.price ASC SEPARATOR ","), ",", 1) AS `price` 

FROM `products` 

LEFT JOIN `products_photos` ON `products`.`id` = `products_photos`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `products_attributes` ON `products`.`id` = `products_attributes`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `products_categories` ON `products`.`id` = `products_categories`.`product_id` 

WHERE `products_categories`.`category_id` = '5' AND `products`.`status` = '1' 

GROUP BY `products`.`id` 

ORDER BY `ord` ASC
```

I'm wondering about photos and attributes part of query, is there a better way to select first photo and smallest price from joined tables?
There will be a lot of products in my table and I'm worried about future performance as I'm not very good at MySQL :)

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of working code.

Comment: oh, i'am sorry, haven't seen information about code reveiw, never gonna do it again :)